# Get data related for each ID in a parent/child Database in tSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recursion, common-table-expression

I work with the following table

```
-- USER TABLE --
User_ID | Manager_ID | Code
1       | null       | ABC
2       | 1          | DEF
3       | 2          | HIJ
4       | null       | ABC
```

I need to know the codes related for each users and if the code is "owned" or not. A related code is "owned" by the user when the code is in the same row

*User_ID = **1** : Owned Code = **ABC***

But I also need to know the codes related for each user by the hierarchy Manager_ID -> User_ID. This hierarchy doesn't have a max depth.

*User_ID = **1** : Related Code = **DEF** (by User_ID 2) and **HIJ** (by User_ID 3)*

In my example, I'd like to get the following result

```
User_ID | Code | IsOwner
1       | ABC  | 1
1       | DEF  | 0
1       | HIJ  | 0
2       | DEF  | 1
2       | HIJ  | 0
3       | HIJ  | 1
4       | ABC  | 1
```

For the owned code, is simple, I did the following query :

```
SELECT User_ID, Code, 1 as IsOwner
FROM User
```

But I met some issues with the hierarchy. I tried to find example on the internet but I only see requests with "level" or "count" and I don't know how to retrieve all the related codes.

I saw Common Table Expression and tried queries like that, but I think I'm missing something...

```
USE MyBD
GO
WITH MyCTE (Manager_ID, User_ID, Code, IsOwned)
AS
(
    SELECT Manager_ID, User_ID, Code, 1 as IsOwned
    FROM User
    WHERE Manager_ID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT u.Manager_ID, u.User_ID, u.Code, 1 as IsOwned
    FROM User AS u
    INNER JOIN Managers AS d
        ON u.Manager_ID = d.User_ID
)
SELECT Manager_ID, User_ID, Code, IsOwned
FROM Managers
GO
```

Can you help me to get all the related codes for each users and their ownership ?

Comment: you have a max depth of hierarchy, or not ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus No I don't have a max depth, I edit my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the only way I found, finally, is to keep a trace of the hierarchy with concatenation, then split the concatenated value.

```
WITH Managers 
AS
(
    SELECT Manager_ID, User_ID,   Code,  cast(User_ID as varchar(max))  as hierarchy
    FROM Users
    WHERE Manager_ID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT u.Manager_ID, u.User_ID,  u.Code,  d.hierarchy + case when d.hierarchy <> '' then '_' else '' end +  cast(u.user_id as varchar)
    FROM Users AS u
    INNER JOIN Managers AS d
        ON u.Manager_ID = d.User_ID
)

SELECT splitdata, Code, case when splitdata = user_id then 1 else 0 end as IsOwner

FROM
 (
 SELECT *,
 -- this part, for readability, should be replace by a split function
 cast('<X>'+replace(F.hierarchy,'_','</X><X>')+'</X>' as XML) as xmlfilter from Managers F
 )a
 CROSS APPLY
 ( 
 SELECT cast(fdata.D.value('.','varchar(50)') as int) as splitdata 
 FROM a.xmlfilter.nodes('X') as fdata(D)) s
 order by splitdata, Code
```

see [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a1e242/13).

The sqlfiddle has also a part with the result of the CTE only, to help understanding.

**EDIT**

As there may be a misunderstanding (about what's an Owner), here's the previous version, with corrections by Tom Chantler !

```
WITH Managers 
AS
(
    SELECT Manager_ID, User_ID, user_ID as topManager, Code
    FROM Users
    WHERE Manager_ID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT u.Manager_ID, u.User_ID, d.topManager as topManager,  u.Code
    FROM Users AS u
    INNER JOIN Managers AS d
        ON u.Manager_ID = d.User_ID
)

select topManager, Code, 0 from Managers
where manager_ID is not null
union
select user_ID, Code, CASE WHEN topManager = User_Id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END from Managers
union
select Manager_ID, Code, 0 from Managers
where Manager_ID is not null;
```

Comment: This is great. I was working on something similar, but I think this is better.

Comment: @TomChantler Hmmm, sadly I  think some levels will not be returned if the depth of hierarhcy has more levels...

Comment: Check this out: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a1e242/4 I have added some extra hierarchy, which doesn't work as you said, but then I changed the new "owner" column from `1` to `CASE WHEN topManager = User_Id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` so that it only shows if the user is the top manager. It works, maybe you can update your answer?

Comment: @TomChantler think it's still not exactly that (no NOP with IsOwner = 1 for example), but think I got it now. I put my new result with yours, you can see some difference. By the way, nice challenge ;) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a1e242/12

Comment: NOP shouldn't have IsOwner = 1 because it is only actually owned by User_id 1. What I mean is, I _think_ my solution was correct based on my understanding of the question. And yours is obviously correct based on your understanding. But I _do_ like your stuff, it's cool :-)

Comment: @TomChantler oh, you're maybe right then. I add your solution as alternative, hope you don't mind.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus / TomChantler : I'm back. I did some tests with real data. These two requests are very interesting, btw only the first one with split give me the right ownership. A bit complex but it's a nice training for me :) Good job !

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus: that's cool. Teamwork is cool and it's only the end result that matters. In any case, it looks like your version was right anyway. Alex, I'm glad you have everything sorted now. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have made some small modifications to your query. Try the following: I removed the where conditions in the first query, becuase you need to get the heirarchy for all the users, not only managers. And also changed the join conditions

```
;WITH MyCTE (Manager_ID, User_ID, Code, IsOwned)
AS
(
    SELECT User_ID, User_ID, Code, 1 as IsOwned
    FROM [User]

    UNION ALL
    SELECT d.Manager_ID, u.User_ID, u.Code, 0 as IsOwned
    FROM [User] AS u
    INNER JOIN MyCTE AS d
        ON u.Manager_ID = d.User_ID
)
SELECT Manager_ID, User_ID, Code, IsOwned
FROM MyCTE ORDER BY Manager_ID,Code;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried your queries and also made some changes. I can get the hierarchy but only from down to top... In my example I get (3, HIJ, 1) (3, DEF, 0) and (3, ABC, 0). I feel so close but meet some difficulties to understand these CTE.